# C++11 atomic classes and operations -- am I right

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Am I right in the following assumptions:

- I don't need to explicitly synchronize an access to the `std::atomic<T>` objects from different threads on any platform with my own synchronization objects
- `std::atomic<T>` operations could be lock-free or non-lock-free, dependent on the platform
- `std::atomic_bool` and `std::atomic<bool>` (and the other types like these) are the same things actually
- `std::atomic_flag` is the only class that guarantees platform-independent lock-free operations by the standard

Also where can I find a useful info about `std::memory_order` and how to use it properly?

Comment: If there is a better summary of `std::memory_order` than that on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) I haven't yet found it. I'd start with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go through one by one.

---

- I don't need to explicitly synchronize an access to the `std::atomic<T>` objects from different threads on any platform with my own synchronization objects

Yes, `atomic` objects are fully synchronized on all of their accessor methods.

The only time a data race can occur with access to the atomic types is during construction, but it involves constructing an atomic object `A`, passing its address to another thread via an atomic pointer using `memory_order_relaxed` to intentionally work around the sequential consistency of `std::atomic`, and then accessing `A` from that second thread. So, don't do that? :)

Speaking of construction, there are three ways to initialize your atomic types:

```
// Method 1: constructor
std::atomic<int> my_int(5);

// Method 2: atomic_init
std::atomic<int> my_int; // must be default constructed
std::atomic_init(&my_int, 5); // only allowed once

// Method 3: ATOMIC_VAR_INIT
// may be implemented using locks even if std::atomic<int> is lock-free
std::atomic<int> my_int = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(5);
```

Using either of the two latter methods, the same data race possibility applies.

---

- `std::atomic<T>` operations could be lock-free or non-lock-free, dependent on the platform

Correct. For all integral types, there are macros you can check that tell you whether a given `atomic` specialization is not, sometimes, or always lock-free. The value of the macros is 0, 1, or 2 respectively for these three cases. The full list of macros is taken from §29.4 of the standard, where `unspecified` is their stand-in for "0, 1, or 2":

```
#define ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_CHAR16_T_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_SHORT_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_LLONG_LOCK_FREE unspecified 
#define ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE unspecified
```

Note that these defines apply to both the unsigned and signed variants of the corresponding types.

In the case that the `#define` is 1, you have to check at runtime. This is accomplished as follows:

```
std::atomic<int> my_int;

if (my_int.is_lock_free()) {
    // do lock-free stuff
}

if (std::atomic_is_lock_free(&my_int)) {
    // also do lock-free stuff
}
```

---

- `std::atomic_bool` and `std::atomic<bool>` (and the other types like these) are the same things actually

Yes, these are just `typedef`s for your convenience. The full list is found in Table 194 of the standard:

```
Named type      | Integral argument type
----------------+-----------------------
atomic_char     | char
atomic_schar    | signed char
atomic_uchar    | unsigned char
atomic_short    | short
atomic_ushort   | unsigned short
atomic_int      | int
atomic_uint     | unsigned int
atomic_long     | long
atomic_ulong    | unsigned long
atomic_llong    | long long
atomic_ullong   | unsigned long long
atomic_char16_t | char16_t
atomic_char32_t | char32_t
atomic_wchar_t  | wchar_t
```

---

- `std::atomic_flag` is the only class that guarantees platform-independent lock-free operations by the standard

Correct, as guaranteed by §29.7/2 in the standard.

Note that there's no guarantee on the initialization state of `atomic_flag` unless you initialize it with the macro as follows:

```
std::atomic_flag guard = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // guaranteed to be initialized cleared
```

There is a similar macro for the other atomic types,

The standard does not specify if `atomic_flag` could experience the same data race other atomic types could have during construction.

---

- Also where can I find a useful info about `std::memory_order` and how to use it properly?

As suggested by @WhozCraig, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) has the best reference.

And as @erenon suggests, [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic/thread_coordination.html) has a great essay on how to use memory fences for lock-free programming.

Comment: [Boost.Atomic][0]s essay on memory_order is easier to understand IMHO.

[0]: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic/thread_coordination.html

Comment: This is one of the most thorough and clear answers I've ever read on StackOverflow.

Comment: i guess concurrency in action is ok book for memory_order stuff, but i dont recall exactly...